# Read and write flv files from SD Card

Tags: android, file, android-listview, flv

I am Working on Video Player Project. I want it to Scan my SD Card for all FLV file format &  display video's  in  List View.

I am using this Tutorial [LINK](http://gypsynight.wordpress.com/2012/02/17/how-to-show-all-video-file-stored-in-your-sd-card-in-a-listview/)

Comment: ok than what is exact problem?

Comment: this might help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997775/how-to-get-list-of-videos-on-sd-card

Comment: see my edited link it is a working example

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I tought that the question was about plv playing, my bad. It is about getting a list of the *.flv files on the SD. What about [`MediaStore.Files`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Files.html) (assuming that `MediaStore.Video` won't catch .flv files)?

Old Answer:

FLV is not among the Android [supported formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html), although some manufqacturer may have extended their version of Android to include it.

I would suggest to take a look to [Vitamio](https://www.vitamio.org/), A replacement of the Android `MediaPayer` with support for more formats.