# Retrieve all video files on Android device

Tags: c#, android, video, unity-game-engine

I am trying to implement video player feature in my Unity3D-Android app. Would like to know that how to access all video files present on device storage. So far I could get list of MP4 files on `Application.persistentDataPath` using this :

```
private List<string> DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    List<string> files = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir,"*.mp4"))
        {
            files.Add(f);
        }
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
        {
            files.AddRange(DirSearch(d));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.LogError(ex.Message);
    }

    return files;
}
```

To use the same piece of code for entire device storage and SD card, Where should I start my search from?

**EDIT :**

Please note that I am working in Unity3D with C# and above code works fine. So a java code would not be helpful. Instead I need absolute path on android device storage for which I can call above method like this: `DirSearch(needThisPathAddressForAndroidRootFolder)`

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list all video files on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399361/how-to-list-all-video-files-on-device)

Comment: @Mick This question is for unity3D c# whereas your linked question is for native android.

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer to this? I have the same problem now.

Comment: This is a rather old question, I don't have the exact solution but you need a plugin to get the path. Have a look at [this question](https://answers.unity.com/questions/946029/get-sdcard-root-path.html)

Answer (score -1):

Query the `MediaStore`  content provider

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html

An example could be

```
public static void printNamesToLogCat(Context context) {
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA };
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int vidsCount = 0;
    if (c != null) {
        vidsCount = c.getCount();
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("VIDEO", c.getString(0));
        }
        c.close();
    }
}
```

Thank you [slartibartfast](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081340/slartibartfast)

[Referenced By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997775/how-to-get-list-of-videos-on-sd-card)

Comment: I am working in Unity3D so native code wont help. I appreciate your response