# How to list all video files on device

Tags: android

I want to get all videos path in android (Internal and External storage both), I have tried use:

```
List<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
File directory = new File("/system" OR "/mnt/sdcard");
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
    if(files[i].getAbsolutePath().contains(".mp4")) {
       paths.add(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

but I can not get all of video lists from my device.

Comment: Query the `MediaStore`.

Comment: please give me a sample code about it

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v7.6/DragDrop/Action/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/dragdrop/MainActivity.java#L123-L139

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make your search recursive.  Something like:

```
void findVideos(File dir, ArrayList<String> list){
    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) findVideos(file, list);
        else if(file.getAbsolutePath().contains(".mp4")) list.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

Here is your solution must try if you want to really a actual result.

```
  public ArrayList<String> getAllMedia() {
    HashSet<String> videoItemHashSet = new HashSet<>();
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA ,MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};
    Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
    try {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do{
            videoItemHashSet.add((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA))));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());

        cursor.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayList<String> downloadedList = new ArrayList<>(videoItemHashSet);
    return downloadedList;
}
```

Comment: If you add video with adb, it won't be added to content provider, and you do not get it with this method. In the other hand, accepted answer searches through all files

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<VideoClass> videoItems = new ArrayList<VideoClass>();

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);

    //looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE));
            Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID)));
            Bitmap vimage =
                    null;
            try {
                vimage = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().loadThumbnail(
                        contentUri, new Size(640, 480), null);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            VideoClass  videoModel  = new VideoClass();
            videoModel.setTitle(title);
            videoModel.setMain_video(String.valueOf(contentUri));
            videoModel.setImage(vimage);
            videoItems.add(videoModel);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return videoItems;
```

Comment: above code is correct but user have to give storage permission also
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Answer (score -2):

```
String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE));
Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID)));
Bitmap vimage = null;
try {
   vimage = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().loadThumbnail(contentUri, new Size(640, 480), null);
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```