# Set MediaPlayer.SetDataSource() to '/storage/emulated/0/...'

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm getting media that's on the phone as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17999170/939213)  (using `ContentResolver`) but the path returned is of the form `/storage/emulated/0/...` and trying to use it for `mediaPlayer.SetDataSource()` yields a `Java.IO.FileNotFoundException`. I realize that this path is probably not a real path, but how do I get the real path from this path?

When I have an Asset in the project folder, the `MediaPlayer` works fine. But I can't get it to work with other files. I already set the permission for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` .

Though I rather have an answer in C#, An answer in Java would probably be enough.

**EDIT**

I've seen some answers dealing with similar things but they all assume I have a `Uri`. While the method above returns a string. And I haven't been successful in trying to convert it to a Uri so I can't even test those solutions.

Comment: "I realize that this path is probably not a real path" -- there is certainly nothing wrong with `/storage/emulated/0/`. Whether the file exists is another matter. "I already set the permission for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ." -- I have no idea how Xamarin handles runtime permissions, but you need that too, most likely. Also note that the approach that you are using will not work for all media (e.g,. media on removable storage).

Comment: @CommonsWare It's not on removable media. It's a file I put on the phone using a USB cable and Windows Explorer. And the path is returned as `Data` by the method mentioned in the question. So what might be the problem?

Comment: I mentioned [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) as being a possibility.

Comment: I don't understand. As I've said in the question - I've already set that.

Comment: "I've already set that" -- if by "set" you mean "you arranged to get it in the app's manifest", that is insufficient. "And I haven't been successful in trying to convert it to a Uri" -- in Java, that would be `Uri.fromFile(new File(something))`, where `something` is a `String` containing your `/storage/emulated/0/`-based value. That will not change your results, though.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks! I didn't know either. That answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

Visit [android: Get real path from uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195731/android-get-real-path-from-uri)

You can get idea about how to get real path from this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass This instead of passing hardcoded value (/storage/emulated/0/)

```
String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/yourFolder/";
```

Don't forget to add permission in manifest file